# Can not run creat a snapshot in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a homework from Distributed Databases.
I try to create a Publication but SQL server 2008 R2 alert error.
I read on support page of MS. They said that must creat a snapshot by manual.
When i do this, and error again:

[image]

Thank for reading and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that the user account you are accessing the system with does not have permission to read\write to the D:\ drive location.  That will need to be fixed first.